# How parallel plates are buried in the soil in real life?

Tags: circuit-design, ground, grounding, ground-plane

From [this site](http://lednique.com/ground-earth-chassis/):

[image]

> The most common reference is Earth itself. Power systems are usually
> “earthed” at some point to provide a reference for the system
> voltages. The earth symbol represents the parallel plates that were
> buried in the soil to ensure good conductivity. (The plates were
> connected by wire and early forms of the symbol show the vertical line
> connecting all the plates. The modern “cleaner” symbol omits the
> vertical.)

I tried to search for the image of parallel plates buried in the soil in real life but couldn't find any image. 
Can anyone provide some images showing how this is done in real life?

Comment: Have you tried searching for “earth pit plate” on Google images; it results some images indicating how this can be done in practice.

Comment: @JakobHalskov I just tried. It seems like the plate is placed vertically/on the site of the plate. However, in the link I sent it seems that they're saying about two or more parallel plates with one on top of the other from bottom to top.

Comment: I agree, it does not match completely with the description. Other than that I have never heard about that explanation.